# CrystalReports asking for Database login credentails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

Hi I have a windows form and a Crystal Report (.rpt) in my project. I am using crystal report viewer to view the report. But when I load the form it asks for the Database logon, i.e, username and password! My DB does not have any username and password, it has integrated security. I have tried checking the integrated security box, leaving the fields empty, but it is not logging me in! Please help, I cannot view the report because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="True">` in the app.config file.