# Crystal report Local Database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have just created a new database (Service Based DAtabase with .mdf extension) in C# local base.
 I can fully work with this but not with crystal reports.

I have created a crystal report, when open it is asking me for user name and password

I have not provided any user name and password while creating this database, nor it asks me to set a user name or password

In C# I make connection at DataAccssesLayer class

```
static string N_c = (@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Perfect\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Visit_Program\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
```

Off course I make data set then connection to database but I don't know why ask me username, password

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

this not ok 100% , but will not ask about user and pass but will show report as empty!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CrystalReports asking for Database login credentails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987250/crystalreports-asking-for-database-login-credentails)